# Ruby - Sort array into sub categories

Tags: ruby

Lets say that I have an array of words, such as this:

```
words = ["apple", "zebra", "boat", "dog", "ape", "bingo"]
```

and I want to sort them alphabetically , but group them like so:

```
sorted = [["ape", "apple"], ["bingo", "boat"], ["dog"], ["zebra"]]
```

How would I be able to do this in Ruby? Help appreciated.

Comment: What is the condition for grouping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to group by the first letter of each word. In which case you can use [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) to sort the array and [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to group by the first character of each word (as returned by [`chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chr)).

```
words = ["apple", "zebra", "boat", "dog", "ape", "bingo"]
sorted = words.sort.group_by(&:chr).values
```

Comment: @Stefan I think `group_by(&:chr)` makes the code more readable than `group_by  {|s| s[0]}` too (avoiding the block in the middle of the line). I've edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
words.sort.chunk { |s| s[0] }.map(&:last)
```

This first sorts the array alphabetically (`.sort`), then it "chunks" together elements with the same first character (`.chunk { |s| s[0] }`), then it grabs the last element from each sub-array `.map(&:last)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick

```
words = ["apple", "zebra", "boat", "dog", "ape", "bingo"]
sorted = words.sort.group_by { |s| s[0] }.map { |k,v| v }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need an array that also represents your categories. In this case, the letters of the alphabet. Below does what you're looking for using nested loops.

```
words = ["apple", "zebra", "boat", "dog", "ape", "bingo"]
results = []
('a'..'z').to_a.each_with_index do |letter, index|
    letter_result = []
    words.each do |word|
        if(word[0]==letter)
            letter_result.push(word)
        end
    end
    unless letter_result.empty?
        results.push(letter_result)
    end
end
```